# Editing a dictionary while looping through its keys

Tags: python-3.x

I have a dictionary:

```
my_dict = {1: ('a', 0, 10), 2: ('b', 3, 12), 3: ('a', 4, 15), 4: ('c', 3, 8), ...}
```

I would like to iterate this dictionary in a specific order, while iterating, when conditions are met I would like to delete multiple items from the dictionary (e.g. delete all delete all keys with values `('a', *, *)`. I would then like to continue looping on the remaining ordered items. As I understand I could do this in two ways:

- Iterating over the dictionary itself, removing elements of the dictionary when necessary. However modifying the iterator you are using is generally advised against and perhaps not even possible in python.
- Iterate over a list of dictionary keys, this has the advantage that I will not be changing the iterator itself, however once items are deleted from the list, the looping indexing will become meaningless and it will not be possible to complete this loop.

So, as far as I can see it is not possible to do this, am I missing something here? Is there an obvious way to do this? Is there custom type buried in a python package somewhere that would satisfy my requirements?

---

Edit:

```
my_dict = {1: ("a", 0, 10), 2: ("b", 3, 12), 3: ("a", 4, 15), 4: ("c", 3, 8), 5: ('b', 3, 12), 6: ('c', 3, 8)}

for k in list(my_dict):
    print(k)
    if k == 3:
        my_dict = {key: value for key, value in my_dict.items() if value[0] != 'c'}

# this prints
# 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
# I want something that prints
# 1, 2, 3, 5 (as all key tuples with 'c' are deleted on the third loop)
```

Comment: Do you actually need to modify the original dict?  The usual way to approach this problem is to not modify the original dict at all, but instead create a **new** dict, copying only the desired items from the original dict.

Comment: Generally, it is better to create a new dictionary, than to delete from an existing dictionary, but it is still possible to do the latter. It isn't clear exactly what problem you are encountering.

Comment: No, and in all likelihood I will be creating a new dictionary every loop so I can update the order. Perhaps I should re-order the dictionary every time and delete the element I just used (and any others i wish to) and then just use the key of the first item in the dictionary on every loop?

Comment: if the order of the dict matters, why not use a list?

Comment: Because lists are slow and I have a lot of elements. Dictionaries are also ordered.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the specific keys using dict-comprehension + `if`:

```py
my_dict = {1: ("a", 0, 10), 2: ("b", 3, 12), 3: ("a", 4, 15), 4: ("c", 3, 8)}

my_dict = {k: v for k, v in my_dict.items() if v[0] != "a"}
print(my_dict)
```

Prints:

```
{2: ('b', 3, 12), 4: ('c', 3, 8)}
```

---

EDIT: To delete keys while iterating the dictionary you can use:

```py
for k in list(my_dict):
    if my_dict[k][0] == "a":
        del my_dict[k]

print(my_dict)
```

Comment: My issue was not how to delete keys but how I can delete them and still iterate through a dictionary in a meaningful way.

Comment: @user17033672 I've updated my answer.

Comment: @user17033672 what is stopping you from doing that? You haven't actually explained what problem you are encountering.